# How do I summarize data that is broken into many columns?

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a data set that contains answers to a "select as many as apply" question with each possible answer in separate columns. So, assuming our question is "What color shirt is acceptable to you?" it looks something like this:

```
id    Q3_Red Q3_Blue Q3_Green    Q3_Purple
9                    
8                    Green       Purple
7                    Green     
6     Red               
5                                Purple
4            Blue          
3            Blue                Purple
2     Red    Blue    Green     
1     Red                        Purple
10    Red                        Purple
```

Which you can make into an actual data frame with:

```
tmp <- data.frame("id" = c(009,008,007,006,005,004,003,002,001,010), "Q3_Red" = c("","","","Red","","","","Red","Red","Red"), "Q3_Blue" = c("","","","","","Blue","Blue","Blue","",""),
  "Q3_Green" = c("","Green","Green","","","","","Green","",""),
  "Q3_Purple" = c("","Purple","","","Purple","","Purple","","Purple","Purple")
)
```

I want to summarize it with a count of each answer, eg.

```
Red     4
Blue    3
Green   3
Purple  5
```

I can get a count of each with something like `tmp %>% count(Q3_Red)` and organize those into their own data frame but it seems like there must be a way to use a reshape function to do this in one fell swoop. I've looked at `gather()` and `spread()` but I can't wrap my head around how I would combine `tidyr` with `count()`.

Comment: The quick and dirty way would be `colSums(tmp[,-1] != "")` but obviously the more formal `tidyverse` way is answered by someone

Comment: @BenToh Thanks. I definitely want to use this project to master the Tidyverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dplyr` and `tidyr` are your friend here:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
tmp %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -id, values_to = "response") %>%   # pivot all columns but id
  filter(response != "") %>%        # remove blanks
  group_by(response) %>%            # group by response
  summarize(count = n())            # summarize and count
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  value  count
  <chr>  <int>
1 Blue       3
2 Green      3
3 Purple     5
4 Red        4
```

Comment: `pivot_longer()` is the new `gather()` in `tidyr` package

Comment: @BenToh Thanks for reminding me that `pivot_longer()` is from `tidyr`. I updated my answer to include reference to both packages.

Comment: For a supplement, `group_by(response) %>% summarize(count = n())` can be simplified as `count(response, name = "count")`, which doesn't need to use `group_by()`.

Comment: @DarrenTsai Thanks. I was actually trying to figure out if there's a reason to use `group_by()` and `summarize(count = n())` instead of just `count()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `na_if()` in `dplyr` to convert `""` to `NA` and then `pivot_longer()` in `tidyr` to stack all columns starting with `Q3`.

***Note:*** *The use of `na_if()` is to make `values_drop_na = T` in `pivot_longer()` work.*

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

tmp %>% 
  mutate(across(-id, na_if, "")) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-id, values_drop_na = T) %>%
  count(value)

# # A tibble: 4 x 2
#   value      n
#   <chr>  <int>
# 1 Blue       3
# 2 Green      3
# 3 Purple     5
# 4 Red        4
```

or use `colSums()` and `tibble::enframe()`

```
tibble::enframe(colSums(tmp[-1] != ""))

# # A tibble: 4 x 2
#   name      value
#   <chr>     <dbl>
# 1 Q3_Red        4
# 2 Q3_Blue       3
# 3 Q3_Green      3
# 4 Q3_Purple     5
```

Answer (score 0):

In base R we can use

```
summary(tmp[-1])
# Q3_Red  Q3_Blue   Q3_Green  Q3_Purple
#     :6       :7        :7         :5  
#  Red:4   Blue:3   Green:3   Purple:5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach

Calculate the frequency per color column

```
tmp2 <- colSums(tmp[, 2:5] != "", na.rm =TRUE)
```

Convert it to a data frame, then convert from rowname to column, finally use regex to remove unnecessary letter to get the expected result

```
tmp2 <- data.frame(tmp2) %>% 
  tibble::rownames_to_column(var = "Colors") %>% 
  mutate(Colors = str_replace_all(Colors, regex("(^.*_)"), "")) %>% 
  rename(freq = tmp2)
#   Colors freq
# 1    Red    4
# 2   Blue    3
# 3  Green    3
# 4 Purple    5
```