# Why is knitr choking on a pipe that works fine otherwise?

Tags: r, knitr

I've got an RMarkdown script that works fine if I run the chunks manually, either one at a time or with "Run All". But when I try to use `knitr` to generate HTML or a PDF, I'm getting an error: `Error in select(responses, starts_with("Q1 ") & !contains("None")) %>%  :  could not find function "%>%"`

The actual full line reads:

`cols <- select(responses, starts_with("Q1 ") & !contains("None") ) %>%  colnames()`

I'm working with data from a survey, where a lot of questions were "select as many as apply" type questions, and there was an open ended "None of the above" option. At this point, I'm pulling out exactly the columns I want (all the Q1 responses, but not Q10 or Q11 responses, and not the open ended response) so I can [use `pivot_longer()` and summarize the responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63311409/how-do-i-summarize-data-that-is-broken-into-many-columns/63312150#63312150). It works fine in the script: I get a list of the exact column names that I want, and then count the values.

But when I try to use `knitr()` it balks on the `%>%`.

```
processing file: 02_Survey2020_report.Rmd
  |....                                                                  |   6%
  ordinary text without R code

  |.........                                                             |  12%
label: setup (with options) 
List of 1
 $ include: logi FALSE

  |.............                                                         |  19%
  ordinary text without R code

  |..................                                                    |  25%
label: demographics gender

Quitting from lines 28-46 (02_Survey2020_report.Rmd) 
Error in select(responses, starts_with("Q1 ") & !contains("None")) %>%  : 
  could not find function "%>%"
Calls: <Anonymous> ... handle -> withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval
Execution halted
```

A simplified reproducible example gets the same results. I run the following and get what I expect, a tidy table with the count times each answer was selected:

```
example <- data.frame("id" = c(009,008,007,006,005,004,003,002,001,010), "Q3_Red" = c("","","","Red","","","","Red","Red","Red"), "Q3_Blue" = c("","","","","","Blue","Blue","Blue","",""),
  "Q3_Green" = c("","Green","Green","","","","","Green","",""), "Q3_Purple" = c("","Purple","","","Purple","","Purple","","Purple","Purple"), 
  "Q3_None of the above" = c(009,008,"Verbose explanation that I don't want to count." ,006,005,004,003,002,"Another verbose entry.",010)
)


cols <- select(example, starts_with("Q3") & !contains("None") ) %>%  colnames()

example %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = all_of(cols), 
               values_to = "response") %>%  
  filter(response != "") %>%   
  count(response)
```

But when I use <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> to output a document, I get the same error:

```
processing file: 00a_reproducible_examples.Rmd

Quitting from lines 9-25 (00a_reproducible_examples.Rmd) 
Error in select(example, starts_with("Q3") & !contains("None")) %>% colnames() : 
  could not find function "%>%"
Calls: <Anonymous> ... handle -> withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval
Execution halted
```

Why is knitr balking at a pipe?

Comment: Did you include `library(dplyr)` or `library(magrittr)` in your Rmd file?

Comment: When you run chunks individually, the chunks run in the global environment. When you knit the document, a fresh environment is created. I suspect you have magrittr loaded in the global environment but don’t have library(magrittr) [or equivalent] in your document.

Comment: I often start my Rmd files with a block that is defined as `\`\`\`{r setup, echo=FALSE, include=FALSE}\n library(dplyr, quietly=TRUE)\n\`\`\`` (pls excuse my `\n` embedded newlines here, code blocks show poorly in comments). Including all libraries that are used is useful for reproducibility and clarity: even if you believe you will only render it from the console interactively, it's serves as a "declarative" block to remind you what's being used. Code maintenance is important even for not-to-be-automated reports.

Comment: @r2evans That's the answer.

Comment: @Limey Superhelpful. And as you can see from the filename, there's a `01_Survey2020_report.Rmd` that is all setup stuff. Reading https://utdata.github.io/rwd-r-reporting-with-data/columns.html#export-the-data to figure out the best way to store and access that.

Answer (score 1):

recently I run into similar problem.
Not sure if there is more sophisticated solution, but loading library in each chunk of code worked for me.
To display result of a code, w/o message regarding library loading add **message = FALSE**.

Example:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, message = FALSE}
library(dplyr)

>>your code with dplyr<<
```
````